# Is there any way to open a Control Panel windows with a const search string?

Tags: windows, controlpanel

I need to open a Control Panel windows with a const search string: `date` directly.

Like this:

[image: Control panel with search string]

Is there any way to save a control.exe search result and reuse it as we does inside the explorer.exe to do this job?

Or any other ways are all acceptable.

Just give me a guidance, specific codes are not necessarily.

Comment: ask this on Microsoft's forum as well.

Comment: Thanks, post it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c757c301-6f2c-4238-aa99-1d05b45359bb/is-there-any-way-to-open-a-control-panel-windows-with-search-string-programmly?forum=windowsdesktopsearchdevelopment) on msdn.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some ideas in the past minutes, so I'll just leave my results here:

1. **Explorer search**: If you use the search functionality in a normal folder, you can save your search and call the file to start it again. There is a [thread in superuser stackexchange](https://superuser.com/q/499238) how to do this. The mentioned `.search.ms` file is based on XML, so maybe someone with better knowledge on Windows path ids can modify such a file to suit your case.
2. **Parameters for control.exe**: I assume you already found the `control.exe` executable in `System32`, which opens the control panel and provides various sub panels via special names, `.cpl` files or the `/page` parameter. I could not find a full command reference for `control.exe`, so maybe there is a parameter for an initial search term, but in my opinion its highly unlikely.
3. **Dirty hacks**: I noticed, that whenever you open the control panel, the search field gets focused and so I wrote a script, which uses the clipboard to insert a search term. I used powershell, but most of this script is copy-pasted from various stackoverflow threads, so it has **very low quality**, but it works. Maybe you can improve this and get rid of `Start-Sleep` part, because the required wait time depends on the time for opening the control panel.

   ```
   [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
   "date" | clip
   Start-Process control.exe
   Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200
   [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{v}")
   ```

Comment: @lukegv  Thanks. Explorer search: It seems to be a way to save the search result of "date" first and then reuse it inside the explorer, but I do not how to save a control panel search result, it seems that control.exe does not offer this opinion. Parameters for control.exe: This is also what I try at first, search on google for a whole afternoon with on result..... Dirty hacks: It works, maybe currently this is the only solution..